# Will changing only a few keywords avoid duplicate content penalties?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

If I reuse the content of the website, for example if the content of my Website for the URL `www.mydomain.com/NewYork` is `The Best Brown Bread in New York`, then if someone opened my other example URL `www.mydomain.com/Chicago` its content should be `The Best Brown Bread in Chicago`.

My content is mostly static but replaced by the last word in the URL, then for `www.mydomain.com/myword` the keyword is "myword" and the output for the content comes like `The Best Brown Bread in myword`

So, in case of large text, replacing just one word or few words will work? Or will Google penalize me for this?

Comment: I think Google will consider this as duplicate content, or a spam webpage. And moreover, you will be serving duplicate content to your users. So I don't think it will result well.

Comment: If the text isn't relevant and the rest of the page content is not duplicated, he won't be really penalized. That'll be a big problem only if it refers to title, headers, or pages with few text.

Comment: Don't forget to approve an answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google will consider it near duplicate content. If there is too much of it on your site, you will be hit by Panda (loss of ranking, your site could be delisted too).

The solution is to use `canonical` or `noindex,follow` on your pages.

See [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en).

Comment: "The most pervasive myth about Panda is that it is about duplicate content. John Mueller has clarified that duplicate content is independent of Panda." https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-algorithm-history/panda-update/

Answer (score 1):

If that text is placed in your `<title>` tag you can very penalized. If your using it as your page title (headers, relevant content) you could get less penalized, but still won't be avoiding it.

For example, if you use `Chicago` and `Chicago-City` as keyword, but you're printing in your title `The Best Brown Bread in Chicago`, you'll get one or both pages penalized.

Check Google Webmaster tips on [title and descriptions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en#3) for sites